# How could I copy __NSCFArray into swift array

Tags: swift

I have a swift array

```
var items: [String] = []
```

How to deep copy a  `__NSCFArray` arry into `items`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know what, NSArray can be simply changed to the swift array using swift functions as?. And yes it will be able to use all the swift functions.

Take this code as an example,

```
let allPeople: NSArray = ["Jack", "Jill", "Johnes"]

if let theSwiftArray = allPeople as? [String]{
  let counts =  theSwiftArray.map(
        {(a: String) -> Int in
            return countElements(a)
        }
    )
    println(counts)
}
```

I hope this helps for you.